# DDD and implementing contract in Application Layer from base class in Infrastructure Layer

Tags: c#, architecture, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

So I had a discussion with a coworker on implementing contract from a Base class to an interface.

We have the following structure with DDD, **Api -> Application -> Domain -> Infrastructure**.
In the infrastructure we use EF Core.

The following code example

**Application**

```
public interface IOrderRepository
{
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }
    Task AddOrderAsync(Order order);
}
```

**Infrasctucture**

```
public class OrderRepository : BaseRepository<Order, DbContext>, IOrderRepository
{
    public OrderRepository(DbContext ctx) : base(ctx) { }

    public async Task AddOrderAsync(Order order)
    {
        try
        {
            await AddAsync(order);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"Exception: {ex}");
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    /*
     * 
     * Some other db methods
     * 
     */
}

public abstract class BaseRepository<T, U> where T : class where U : BaseDbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    protected readonly U _context;

    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _context; 
        } 
    }

    public BaseRepository(U context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected virtual async Task AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        await _context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
    }
}
```

So I am arguing for, instead of implementing **AddNAMEAsync** methods in every repository to make AddAsync **public virtual** in the base class, and in corresponding interfaces and making use of the base class implementation. This way we also still have the possibility to orderride AddAsync if needed and also minimize unneccesary "duplicate code" in repositories.

My coworker on the other hand thinks that this will make the name too generic and when calling the repository you will not know which entity you are adding to the context by just reading the code. And aslo arguing on that we should not expose base class methods in interfaces, but that it instead should only be Parent -> Child exposure.

We are using SOLID principles and each handler only handles one entity/domain aggregate,  we also have very clear naming on our variables/objects so you can easily see what you are adding to the context in the repository name as well as in the domain model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of naming you can, from my point-of-view, safely use "*AddAsync()*". The more important thing is that the client working with the repository uses a type of IOrderRepository. In this case, when looking at *Add****Order****Async*() the *Order* part could be seen as redundant in terms of naming because, first, you are calling it on a type that already indicates that everything is about orders, and second, you are passing an object of type ***Order*** which again indicates what you are going to add.

What you could still do is to make explicit that the generic methods are also part of an generic interface (e.g. IRepository) which IOrderRepository could extend. If you want to derive your infrastructure *OrderRepository* from a base class or if you want to pass it in some other object in terms of favouring composition over inheritance (e.g. a DbContext) is an implementation detail.

You can see an illustration of what I'm referring to [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/d0cd2830a864a8b975341b02b93a0887a3908c04/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/AggregatesModel/OrderAggregate/IOrderRepository.cs) in the microservices reference application of Microsoft ([eshopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AddAsync(T entity)` method in `BaseRepository`, this will be provided reusable code for all your entities but this is already been implemented by Entity Framework Core. Do you really need to implement this structure again?

EF Core already provides the `DbSet` as **base repository** and `DbSet<Order>` as your **order repository**. Also provides `DbContext` as a **unit of work** implementation.

You don't need to create your generic base repository, repository, and unit of work classes if you don't use any other ORM tool or approach of persistence with EF Core. EF Core already provides these patterns as encapsulated.

What will encapsulating the classes and methods provided by EF Core solve in this way?
What are the differences between EF Core's DbSet and your BaseRepository?

See this sample [project](https://github.com/tolgacakir/CleanArchitectureSample)

Comment: There are other limitations needed in the code that requires repository pattern, so there's a reason for that use, one is to limit other developers from querying anything without restrictions

Answer (score 0):

- I think you are right about implementing the AddAsync() method in a base class and inherit other classes from it. Because, when you want to use `AddAsync()` you will first inject the related class and then use it. (It will provide reusable code-base for you)

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
   private readonly OrderService _orderService;
   
   //..
   await _orderService.AddAsync(...);
}
```

- There is no problem in terms of naming in this type of use, because the relevant service and what it will do are very clear.

> Btw, `CreateAsync` or `InsertAsync` could be a better naming in my opinion to demonstrate database operation.